# Using jsoup obtain and redirected link to a link with ?token= in the end

Tags: java, html, cookies, https, jsoup

Here is the link I try to open using my method:

https://www.deviantart.com/download/652802405/sugar_rush_by_rainbow_highway-dasntk5.png?token=2080f7bdd7953b1b5128e45fe1f8d06c6ba8c4f1&ts=1506130109

Here is the code I have for opening it and it doesn't work....

```
public static Document loadURL(String arg) throws IOException
{
    /*
     * This is a method that fake an agent and make a document out of 
     * a url link. 
     */
        try
        {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(arg)
                  .data("query", "Java")
                  .userAgent("Mozilla")
                  .cookie("auth", "token")
                  .timeout(10000)
                  .post();
        return doc;
        }
```

I want to know first of all what does the word ?token= in the end means?

Why does my browser can open the link while this method cannot?

If a web brower can do it, how can I use jsoup to do the samething?

I searched and I kind of get the idea that it is a cookies authentication, but I don't get the detail.(I will probably know how to fake it if I know the details...)

In case you wonder about where is the link on the page, it is here: 
https://rainbow-highway.deviantart.com/art/Sugar-Rush-652802405

Do I need the cookies in this page to redirect or I only need the fancy hex code in at the end of the ?token=   ?????

The link is in the download botton, it is my own DA page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it works for the web site deviant art; 
inspired by a project in github.

https://github.com/4pr0n/ripme/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rarchives/ripme/ripper/rippers/DeviantartRipper.java

```
Map<String,String> cookies = new HashMap<String , String>();

    org.jsoup.Connection.Response resp = 
            Jsoup.connect("https://sorcerushorserus.deviantart.com/art/Dash-Academy-2-Hot-Flank-Part8-263131103")
            .userAgent("Mozilla").execute();

    cookies = resp.cookies();

    Document doc = resp.parse();

    Elements eles = doc.select("a.dev-page-download");

    if(eles.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("We have the downlaod link on this page!");

        String downloadlink = eles.get(0).attr("href");

        System.out.println(":"+downloadlink);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(downloadlink).openConnection();

        String cookiesString = "";

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:cookies.entrySet())
        {
            cookiesString = cookiesString+entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue()+";";
        }

        cookiesString = cookiesString.substring(0, cookiesString.length()-1);

        System.out.println("Cookie String: "+cookiesString);

        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookiesString);

        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla");

        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        con.connect();

        int respondcode = con.getResponseCode();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        String location = con.getURL().toString();

        System.out.println("response code: "+ respondcode);

        System.out.println("image location: "+location);

        con.disconnect();
```

so.... cool...